# How do I read email addresses from a text file?

Tags: python

I have a list of email addresses of recipients in a text file.
How can I get my python script to read the file and recognize it as email addresses?

```
email= open("FILE_PATH_HERE", "r")
print(email.read())
```

Do I have to set it as a string?

Comment: What does the text file look like?

Comment: what does "recognise it as an email address" mean?

Answer (score 1):

`email.read()` returns a string. The problem is, you need to *parse* that string in to list. Assuming this is a simple, one-address-per-line format, you can simply do

```
 addresses = list(email)
```

`email` is an iterable of strings, splitting the single string that `email.read` would return into a list of strings, one per line. `list` can use that iterable to intialize a new `list` instance.

Answer (score 1):

`email` is probably not the best variable name here as you're not getting an email. The call to `open()` is returning a file object. You're subsequently reading the contents of this file when you call `email.read()`. This is returning the entire contents of the file as a single string.

Assuming that your file is simply a list of emails (one per line), the following should work for you.

```py
f = open('my_emails.txt', 'r') # open the file
emails = f.readlines() # returns one string per file line

for email in emails:
  print(email) # prints each line
```